# Is there a way to detect the price of a candle +/- a certain % from the open or close?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to detect bullish/bearish engulfing candles with a bit of wiggle room on either side, as there are sometimes small discrepancies in the price(s). I'd like to detect an engulfing even if the candle open/close is say +/- .01% from the previous open/close.

```
//identify bullish/bearish engulfing candles
bullishEC = close > open[1] and open <= close[1] and close[1] < open[1] 
bearishEC = close < open[1] and open >= close[1] and close[1] > open[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the open[1] and close[1] with required price percentage and then compare. Example

```
bullishEC = close > open[1]*(1-0.01/100) and open <= close[1]*(1+0.01/100) and close[1] < open[1] 
bearishEC = close < open[1]*(1+0.01/100) and open >= close[1]*(1-0.01/100) and close[1] > open[1]
```